# How do I publish private modules using the new npm feature?

Tags: npm, package.json

After entering billing info and re-login my npm client I tried publishing a new private module.

I set `"private": "true"` on `package.json` and gave a name using the scope thing like `@myusername/mymodule`. Then I got an error message on `npm publish` saying that I have to remove `"private": "true"` to publish my module! What am I doing wrong?

Should I remove the private atribute and trust that the simple fact that I gave it a scoped name will make it private by default?

INFO: npm v2.7.6

Answer (score 6):

`"private": true` is *completely different* from private packages. From [docs.npmjs.com](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#private):

> If you set `"private": true` in your package.json, then npm will refuse to publish it. This is a way to prevent accidental publication…

I don’t think that’s what you’re looking for.

Starting in `npm@2.7.0`, if you are a [paid user](https://www.npmjs.com/pricing), you can publish [private packages](https://docs.npmjs.com/private-modules/intro) to the npm registry.

1. Sign up for a paid account.
2. Create and initialize a package with a scoped name, e.g. `"name": "@username/module-name"`.
3. Publish your package. By default, npm assumes scoped packages are intended to be private—this is what you want. However, if you want your scoped package to be public, you can publish with the `--access=public` option.

Comment: Is it possible to publish private packages on a private registry without paid account ?

Comment: @Fractaliste As of 2020: Only user-scoped or org-scoped packages can be published privately. (Non-scoped packages must be public.) And to publish user-scoped packages privately, you must have a paid account on NPM. It doesn’t say explicitly, but I infer that you can publish org-scoped packages privately for free, but only if you're a member of that organization. Read the docs on [Contributing packages to the registry](https://docs.npmjs.com/packages-and-modules/contributing-packages-to-the-registry) for more. Note this only applies to the NPM registry. I can’t speak for other registries.

Answer (score 4):

> Should I remove the private atribute and trust that the simple fact that I gave it a scoped name will make it private by default?

It looks like you should be safe doing that according to [this page](https://docs.npmjs.com/private-modules/intro)!

Specifically:

> All scoped packages default to restricted access. This ensures that you don't make something public by accident. You can change this on the access page.

Comment: I tried doing this but even though it says there is no package with name @user/foo I was able to install it when not logged with my account! Will perform more tests and let you know

Comment: How did you log out?  I'm guessing once you've run `npm login`, you've actually modified your `~/.npmrc` and you'd need to modify that to simulate what it's like to try to access a private module for an unauthenticated user.  Check out the [Logging In](https://www.npmjs.com/private-modules#logging-in) section of the FAQ.

Answer (score 0):

You should set private to false, and if the package is scoped and u don't want it to be downloaded by public, then add a publishConfig in your package.json:

```
"publishConfig": {
    "access": "restricted"
  },
```

That will restrict the package from being publicly viewable and installable.
But the package should be scoped
Or u can use the command

```
yarn publish --access=restricted
```